# c# non rectangular window, library?

Tags: c#, wpf

I know its possible to make a non rectangular window in c#. but i know many programs like windows mediaplayer and other software who got a beautiful layout at the corners etc. but when i draw a circle or something as a non rect. window the system doesnt know what to do with the pixels :S. is there a good way to make beautiful windows for c#, or a library or something?

thnx!

Comment: please specify what kind of technology are you using. Maybe Windows Forms? Or WPF?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [WPF Windows Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748948.aspx):

"Non-Rectangular Window Style

There are also situations where the border styles that WindowStyle allows you to have are not sufficient. For example, you may want to create an application with a non-rectangular border, like Microsoft Windows Media Player uses.

For example, consider the speech bubble window shown in the following figure.
[image]

This type of window can be created by setting the WindowStyle property to None, and by using special support that Window has for transparency.

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    WindowStyle="None"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
    Background="Transparent">
...

</Window>
```

This combination of values instructs the window to render completely transparent. In this state, the window's non-client area adornments (the Close menu, Minimize, Maximize, and Restore buttons, and so on) cannot be used. Consequently, you need to provide your own."

And [an article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984331%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on doing the same in winforms.

Comment: I don't see the "following figure"

Comment: Probably not... as it is a direct quote from the article... click the link.